# Traducir este Codigo vb.net a C#

Tags: c#, vb.net

Como podria traducir este codigo a C#?

```
If TypeOf (ctrl) Is GridView AndAlso Not DirectCast(ctrl, GridView).HeaderRow Is Nothing Then
                Dim grid = DirectCast(ctrl, GridView)
                For i = 0 To (grid.HeaderRow.Cells.Count - 1)
                    Dim _nombre As String = grid.HeaderRow.Cells(i).Text
                    Dim _ctrlP As ControlPantalla = ControlesPantalla.Where(Function(x) x.Nombre = _nombre).FirstOrDefault()
                    If Not _ctrlP Is Nothing Then
                        grid.HeaderRow.Cells(i).Text = _ctrlP.Texto
                    End If
                Next
End If
```

Comment: Buenas. [es.so] no es un servicio de traducción de código :) Debes intentarlo tu y si tienes algun problema al hacer, preguntar algo en concreto. De todas maneras, prueba por ejemplo con [este servicio](http://converter.telerik.com/)

Comment: Incluso [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net) te deja traducir código :^).

Comment: Telerik tiene un convertidor de código, puedes intentar convertirlo allí: [Telerik Code Converter](http://converter.telerik.com/)

Comment: Buenas, probe con varios convertidores pero todos me dan un Error. Este es el error del Telerik.                                                                                                              CONVERSION ERROR: Code could not be converted. Details:

----- Exception 1 of 1 -----
System.NotImplementedException: Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Syntax.IfStatementSyntax not implemented!
   at

Comment: Mejor debería de indicar que quieres que haga, se puede traducir, pero da una flojeraaaaa.

Comment: Necesito preguntar (IF) si una variables es del tipo gridview y si no esta esta casteado (directcast) la variable  en un gridview.

Comment: Pues es extraño, pero parece que varios conversores online están fallando, no se muy bien porqué. Prueba con [mindfusion](https://www.mindfusion.eu/convert-cs-vb.html) que parece que si lo convierte correctamente

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias Pikoh! con el mindfusion logre sacar armar el codigo que necesitaba.

Answer (score 0):

Si no es mucho código puedes hacerlo utilizando la lógica ya que cada lenguaje funciona de forma muy similar, sino puedes usar [Telerik Code Converter](http://converter.telerik.com).

Otro método sería utilizar un `descompilador` para `.NET` y el código en la mayoria te permite seleccionar para descompilar a código `C#` o código `Visual Basic .NET`

1. [dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/)
2. [ILSpy](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy)
3. [JustDecompile .NET](https://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx)